# Lua co-routines

Tags: c++, scripting, lua, coroutine

I'm trying to get an understanding of how I can use co-routines to "pause" a script and wait until some processing is done before resuming.

Perhaps I'm looking at co-routines in the wrong way. But my attempt is structured similar to the example given in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128375/what-are-lua-coroutines-even-for-why-doesnt-this-code-work-as-i-expect-it/5128495#5128495).

The loop in `loop.lua` never reaches a second iteration, and hence never reaches the `i == 4` condition required to exit the running loop in the C code. If I do not yield in `loop.lua`, then this code performs as expected.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <lua/lua.hpp>

bool running = true;

int lua_finish(lua_State *) {
    running = false;
    printf("lua_finish called\n");
    return 0;
}
int lua_sleep(lua_State *L) {
    printf("lua_sleep called\n");
    return lua_yield(L,0);
}

int main() {
    lua_State* L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_register(L, "sleep", lua_sleep);
    lua_register(L, "finish", lua_finish);

    luaL_dofile(L, "scripts/init.lua");

    lua_State* cL = lua_newthread(L);
    luaL_dofile(cL, "scripts/loop.lua");

    while (running) {
        int status;
        status = lua_resume(cL,0);
        if (status == LUA_YIELD) {
            printf("loop yielding\n");
        } else {
            running=false; // you can't try to resume if it didn't yield
            // catch any errors below
            if (status == LUA_ERRRUN && lua_isstring(cL, -1)) {
                printf("isstring: %s\n", lua_tostring(cL, -1));
                lua_pop(cL, -1);
            }
        }
    }

    luaL_dofile(L, "scripts/end.lua");
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

**loop.lua**

```
print("loop.lua")

local i = 0
while true do
    print("lua_loop iteration")
    sleep()

    i = i + 1
    if i == 4 then
        break
    end
end

finish()
```

EDIT: Added a bounty, to hopefully get some help on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return code 2 from `lua_resume` is a `LUA_ERRRUN`. Check the string on the top of the Lua stack to find the error message.

A similar pattern has worked for me, though I did use `coroutine.yield` instead of `lua_yield` and I'm in C rather than C++. I don't see why your solution wouldn't work

On your resume call, it's not clear if you're over simplifying for an example, but I'd make the following changes in your while loop:

```
int status;
status=lua_resume(cL,0);
if (status == LUA_YIELD) {
  printf("loop yielding\n");
}
else {
  running=false; // you can't try to resume if it didn't yield
  // catch any errors below
  if (status == LUA_ERRRUN && lua_isstring(cL, -1)) {
    printf("isstring: %s\n", lua_tostring(cL, -1));
    lua_pop(cL, -1);
  }
}
```

Edit 2:

For debugging, add the following before you run your resume. You've got a string getting pushed on the stack somewhere:

```
int status;
// add this debugging code
if (lua_isstring(cL, -1)) {
  printf("string on stack: %s\n", lua_tostring(cL, -1));
  exit(1);
}
status = lua_resume(cL,0);
```

Edit 3:

Oh good grief, I can't believe I didn't see this already, you don't want to run `luaL_dofile` when you're going to yield because you can't yield a pcall directly as best I know, which is what happens in the dofile (5.2 will pass it through, but I think you still need the lua_resume).  Switch to this:

```
luaL_loadfile(cL, "scripts/loop.lua");
```

Comment: The error code 2 only occurs when the resume code is successively run (more than one, without another yield). Any other error I get is: "attempt to call a string value". The pop code: `if (lua_isstring(cL, -1)) {
  printf("isstring: %s\n", lua_tostring(cL, -1));
  lua_pop(cL, -1);
 }`

Comment: "attempt to call a string" means something else is on the stack other than your routine, possibly an error message. And when resume finishes with a return 0, the routine is done and you can't resume it any more, it's no longer on the stack. You can only resume again if you got a yield last time or pushed a new routine on the stack.

Comment: How can I get the error message, if not through the code above?

Comment: I don't think we have enough code to give you a good answer.  You say that you're checking for an error message on the stack, but then you're trying to call a string value when you run the resume?  I'll update my answer with at least one tip.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however thats the exact same control sequence I was using :/. Ill give it another shot tonight.

Comment: @Daniel: any luck? If not, some more code on your while loop and error handling may help.

Comment: none yet, but I havent tried your full permutation yet. Uni's kept me busy writing assembly (lol).

Comment: `init.lua \n
loop.lua \n
lua_loop iteration \n
lua_sleep called \n
isstring: attempt to call a string value \n
end.lua \n`

It appears it is resuming the thread, hence only the non existent error message. But if I let it loop (ie remove `running = false`) then it attempts to resume the thread, which hasn't actually run, and errors: `isstring: cannot resume non-suspended coroutine
`. Updated original code.

Comment: @Daniel: once it errors, the thread is dead, and you have to create a new one. I don't see anything that's pushing a string on the stack. It's worth popping that string off and printing it after the lua_resume yields to see what's there.

Comment: @Daniel: note that in 5.2, you can yield through a pcall which would let you catch an error and reuse a thread (though not resume it since the error would pop the function off the stack).

Comment: @Daniel: see my 3rd edit, you need the loadfile instead of dofile for code that can yield.

Comment: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAH. luaL_loadfile(cL, "scripts/loop.lua");

It all works now... *crys*. Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel, you're welcome, still can't believe I didn't see that until now.

Answer (score 1):

Last time i was messing with Lua coroutines I ended with such code

```
const char *program =
"function hello()\n"
"  io.write(\"Hello world 1!\")\n"
"  io.write(\"Hello world 2!\")\n"
"  io.write(\"Hello world 3!\")\n"
"end\n"
"function hate()\n"
"  io.write(\"Hate world 1!\")\n"
"  io.write(\"Hate world 2!\")\n"
"  io.write(\"Hate world 3!\")\n"
"end\n";

const char raw_program[] = 
"function hello()\n"
"  io.write(\"Hello World!\")\n"
"end\n"
"\n"
"cos = {}\n"
"\n"
"for i = 0, 1000, 1 do\n"
"  cos[i] = coroutine.create(hello)\n"
"end\n"
"\n"
"for i = 0, 1000, 1 do\n"
"  coroutine.resume(cos[i])\n"
"end";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    lua_State *Lt[1000];
    global_State *g = G(L);

    printf("Lua memory usage after open: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    luaL_openlibs(L);

    printf("Lua memory usage after openlibs: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    lua_checkstack(L, 2048);

    printf("Lua memory usage after checkstack: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    //lua_load(L, my_lua_Reader, (void *)program, "code");
    luaL_loadbuffer(L, program, strlen(program), "line");

    printf("Lua memory usage after loadbuffer: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    int error = lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (error) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    printf("Lua memory usage after pcall: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        Lt[i] = lua_newthread(L);
        lua_getglobal(Lt[i], i % 2 ? "hello" : "hate");
    }

    printf("Lua memory usage after creating 1000 threads: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        lua_resume(Lt[i], 0);
    }

    printf("Lua memory usage after running 1000 threads: %d\n", g->totalbytes);

    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems you could not load file as coroutine? but use function instead And it should be selected to the top of the stack.

```
lua_getglobal(Lt[i], i % 2 ? "hello" : "hate");
```

Comment: No need to create the coroutine in the Lua script, the `lua_newthread` call does that in C/C++. I use it myself without any issues.

Comment: Actually I don't load raw_program. I should cut it from my post. But yes I see. The problem is with resuming coroutine. not starting them. should read original post carefully

Comment: Just saw that you're using `lua_newthread` in your example. But yeah, OP has issues after yielding the coroutine.